# Get parent method with fixed generic parameter by reflection

Tags: java, generics, methods, reflection

Let's have this class structure:

```
abstract class Event {}
class EventImpl extends Event {}

class Foo<T extends Event> {
  public void foo(T event) {}
}

class FooImpl extends Foo<EventImpl> {
}
```

I'm trying to find by reflection the `Method` `foo` from a `FooImpl` instance. I suposed this should work:

```
FooImpl fooImpl = new FooImpl();
Class clazz = fooImpl.getClass();
Method foo = clazz.getMethod("foo", EventImpl.class);
```

However, I'm getting a `NoSuchMethodException`. It seems to be that the generic parameter `T`, fixed as `EventImpl`, cannot be recognized as a method parameter, because if I try to find the method in this way, is working fine:

```
Method fooParent = clazz.getMethod("foo", Event.class);
```

Is normal this behaviour or I'm missing something here?
Thanks for the help.

*Just a basic test to help to reproduce the error:*

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
  FooImpl fooImpl = new FooImpl();
  // Method foo of class FooImpl need to be called with parameter EventImpl
  fooImpl.foo(new EventImpl());

  Class clazz = fooImpl.getClass();
  Method fooParent = clazz.getMethod("foo", Event.class);   // OK
  Method foo = clazz.getMethod("foo", EventImpl.class);     // NoSuchMethodException
}
```

Comment: You did not override the method in your class `FooImpl`. By doing so, your test will pass.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually this was my temporary solution, but I thought that could be other choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the **[type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)** of **generics**.

From the Oracle Docs:

> **Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds** or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

Since `Reflection` is a runtime phenomenon, due to type erasure of generics, `foo`'s parameter is replaced to `Event` (Since it's bound by `T extends Event`).

Hence, you have to pass the `Event.class` as the argument.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It seems to be that I need to review some basic concepts about type erasure :) By now it has become clear to me

Answer (score 1):

The keyword here is: ***bridge methods***.

When compiled, the `FooImpl` will not *directly* expose a method `foo` with a parameter of type `Event`, but it might rather generate an additional (bridge) method (as part of the type erasure process) to ensure that subtyping works as expected:

```
public void foo(Event event) {
    foo((EventImpl) event);
}

private void foo(EventImpl eventImpl) {

}
```

At Runtime, when your Reflection snipped will be executed and after type erasure has already taken place, the `T` type-parameter would have already been successfully replaced with `Event`, but when invoked, the bridge method will help *delegates* to the original `foo` method that uses an `EventImpl` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the advise